# routine program in ubuntu

Tags: programming, c++, scripts

I am trying to write a routine of my studies of next month. 
For that I want to write a timed schedule. That is a timed program that will tell me everytime I turn on my laptop which topics should I read at that date. 
I can divide a day into 3 parts: 8AM-2PM, 2PM-6PM and 6PM-8AM. 
And now I don't want any routine softwares, I want to write that program myself.
 All I am asking is what language should I know before I can write this program??? Should I learn shell scripting? 
 I know a bit of C++, will that help?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is enough to implement this kind of function.
besides ,you should choose a gui library for show.
Shell is not necessary。

Comment: So what should I know then,I dont need any graphical show, a terminal pop-up would do.. I know really little,Which topics should I learn??

Comment: @TamimAdDari In simple term. you could use python。which is very easy to implement something,and it was a cross-platform language. could run both in Window and Linux platform